# Enumerating network interfaces and setting them to promiscuous mode in a loadable kernel module

Tags: kernel, freebsd, wireless

I need to set all wireless interfaces to promiscuous mode in a loadable kernel module.

What KPIs are there to enumerate network interfaces?  What KPI should I call to set the interface to promiscuous mode?

I've been looking through the ifconfig(1) code but this is userland, not kernel land.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `struct ifnet * ifnet_byindex(u_short idx)` in order to get interface pointer. If you want to get close an personal, interfaces are maintained on V_ifnet list which you can iterate over.

FreeBSD's man [ifnet(9)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ifnet) provides a decent overview of interface-related in-kernel API. `ifpromisc()` sounds like what you may need to control promiscuous mode.